# Sublime Text 3 getting Less-Build not working

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm trying to get Less-Build to work in Sublime Text 3. As documented I went to the package, unzipped it, ran the .bat file choosing 1 for normal, then I zipped it up again, and renamed back to .sublime-package.  The .bat said the symlink was good?  But there's not LESS build option, and if it did work when does automatic build occur or do I have to keep choosing the build each time I open Sublime?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so the instructions to install the Less-Build plugin for Sublime Text 3 using Package Control:

1. Download using Package Control
2. Browse Packages
3. Unzip Less-Build.sublime-package to Less-Build folder
4. Run either .sh or .bat depending on OS
5. Make sure symlink is all good after choosing build type, and here's the missing line
6. Move the folder out of Installed Packages to User/Packages/Less-Build

I don't know, it might just be me but that last line doesn't appear to be documented.  Hope this helps someone.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Plugins are run directly from the `sublime-package` files, rather than needing to be extracted as in ST2. I'd recommend creating an issue on the plugin page to add `.no-sublime-package` to the root of the plugin. This will tell package control to always extract the contents of the package, rather than letting it remain bundled up (effectively placing it in the Packages folder when you install). I suppose there is still a possibility of overriding happening, but I don't think it will, based on the fact that is how PC worked in ST2 with this plugin. There might have been some overriding issue with the leaving it in the `.sublime-package` file.

Glad you found a solution though. I know this isn't really an answer, but the above is to long for a comment.